# Why OleFileIO_PL only works with .doc file types and not .docx Python?

Tags: python-2.7

right so I'm working on a Python script (Python 2.7) that will extract the metadata from OLE files. I am using OleFileIO_PL and it work perfectly file with OLE files 97 - 2003, but any later then that it just says that it is not an OLE2 file type.

Any way I can modify my code to support both .doc and .docx ? Same with .ppt and .pptx etc.

Thank you in advance

Source Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-   

import OleFileIO_PL
import StringIO
import optparse
import sys
import os

def printMetadata(fileName):
   data = open(fileName, 'rb').read()
   f = StringIO.StringIO(data)
   OLEFile = OleFileIO_PL.OleFileIO(f)
   meta = OLEFile.get_metadata()
   print('Author:', meta.author)
   print('Title:', meta.title)
   print('Creation date:', meta.create_time)
   meta.dump()
   OLEFile.close()


def main():
  parser = optparse.OptionParser('usage = -F + Name of the OLE file with the extention For example: python Ms Office Metadata Extraction Script.py -F myfile.docx ')
  parser.add_option('-F', dest='fileName', type='string',\
     help='specify OLE (MS Office) file name')
  (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
  fileName = options.fileName
  if fileName == None:
     print parser.usage
     exit(0)
  else:
     printMetadata(fileName)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Comment: A quick search finds [openxmllib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openxmllib/1.0.7), which looks like it could help for the newer formats.

Comment: Thank you I tried openxmllib not going to lie I had quite a lot of trouble installing it but I managed. Now that it is installed I will look at the documentation and write a metadata extraction script. Should work hopefully. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, this is because the newer MS Office 2007+ files (docx, xlsx, xlsb, pptx, etc) have a completely different structure from the legacy MS Office 97-2003 formats.

It is mainly a collection of XML files within a Zip archive. So with a little bit of work, you can extract everything you need using zipfile and ElementTree from the standard library.

If openxmllib does not work for you, you may try other solutions:

- officedissector: https://www.officedissector.com/
- python-opc: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-opc
- openpack: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpack
- paradocx: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paradocx

BTW, OleFileIO_PL has been renamed to **olefile**, and the new project page is https://github.com/decalage2/olefile